# How to know a file is writing via NSFileManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsfilemanager

I got a problem , How to know the file is accessible ???

For example , the file is writing , but not finish yet.
And I check the file again ,

I use

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
```

It return true ... but the file is not accessible .

How to determine the file is ready ?

Thanks

Webber

**EDIT**
Maybe I'm not telling my problem clearly . I mean if you start transport a video file . before transport finish . the video file is not accessible , but you still can get a part of transporting file.

Comment: "isReadableFileAtPath" can help.

Comment: isReadableFileAtPath not work , even the file is only one byte , it will return true .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSFileCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/index.html) and [NSFilePresenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)NSFilePresenter) are created just for that. You may find interesting [Advanced iCloud Document Storage](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#237) video from wwdc that covers the usage of this classes. [Building a Document-based App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#234) will be great to watch too.

Comment: Pretty close what I looking for , never read this document before ,Thanks

Comment: NSFileCoordinator and NSFilePresenter works only if file moved using another NSFilePresenter. That means if other app, for example, using NSFileManager, you will not be notified when file deleted or created.

Answer (score 1):

Write Data in async way using GCD concept and once it is completed, the completion handler will be executed.(Where completion of a writing process shall be detected)

The dispatch I/O convenience API lets you perform asynchronous read and write operations on file descriptors. This API supports stream-based semantics for accessing the contents of the file-descriptor.

Method:

```
void dispatch_write ( dispatch_fd_t fd, dispatch_data_t data, dispatch_queue_t queue, void (^handler)(dispatch_data_t data, int error) );
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_write

Comment: I think I got some idea form your reply , and yes , I was using stream writing file .

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to check the attributes of the file and particullary the `NSFileBusy` attribute:

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    NSLog(@"File Busy %@", [attributes objectForKey:NSFileBusy]);
}
```

Comment: Hey , I only can got "File Busy (null)", I don't know why , but I check the attribute-fileSIzE and fileModificationDate , it changed every time before the async writing finish.

Comment: You can check the fileSize and compare it to the original file size every X number of milliseconds, let's say 100, and once the target file size matches the source file size you've know the copy operation did complete

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch data of file by using following code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSData *readData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: I think it will not work ... because you can get the data , but they are not complete file . just a part of data .
But still thanks for your reply .